# I can't get the timestamp for today

Tags: php, timestamp

I am trying to create a Gantt chart module for one of my programs. the problem is that I am using `timestamp`s for storing time in data base. Here is the problem:

```
<?php
$now=time();
echo date('s:i:H d/m/y',$now); //returns: 22:51:07 15/09/15
echo '<br>';
echo $now; // returns: 1442296282
echo '<br>';
echo $now%86400; // returns: 21082
echo '<br>';
echo $today=$now-($now%86400); 
// so I Subtract modulated diffrence so that I can access 0:0:0 for today
echo '<br>';
echo date('s:i:H d/m/y',$today);
//returns: 00:00:02 15/09/15
echo '<br>';
echo mktime(0,0,0,9,15,2015); // (timestamp for today at 0:0:0)returns:1442268000
?>
```

I know the way around and I know how I can access to timestamp of 0:0:0 for today without this basically way. (Although it would be great to know better ways) but the main propose of this question is to know what is the problem of this logic or algorithm that won't work.

Comment: Try this `date('s:i:H d/m/y');`

Comment: @aldrin27 I can't see how is this any help, `date('s:i:H d/m/y');` returns todays date and time, I have it on my line 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two hours offset is due to your timezone (probably +2 UTC). `time()` returns the time according to UTC, while `date()` converts it to the local timezone (adding +2 in your case).

So if you're taking `time()` reducing the amount of seconds of the day - you get to midnight UTC. Then printing it out using `date()` shows your the local time - around 2am.

Therefore:

1. If you want to see the time in UTC as well, you should use `gmdate()` instead of `date()`.
2. If you want `$today` to hold the the time passed since EPOCH in your local time, you should then substract the timezone difference: (`$today -= (int)substr(date('O'),0,3)*60*60`).

The method you should choose depends on the timezone of the data in your DB.